# How to parse json response from ajax?

Tags: ajax, json

I am new to json and ajax this is my first example can any one help me out with this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
     url: "ajs/index",
     dataType: "JSON",
     success: function(data) {          
     var obj = JSON.parse(data);
     $("#result").html(obj.name);
      }
   });
```

The output of data is of the form:

```
[Object {id=10, name="ss", title="ss", content="h", ...}, Object {id=12, name="lo", title="gi", content="c", ...}, Object {id=13, name="lo", title="gi", content="c", ...}, Object {id=14, name="lo", title="gi", content="c", ...}, Object {id=15, name="n", title="m", content="m", ...}]
```

The output of obj(after parsing) is of the form:

```
[{"id":10,"name":"ss","title":"ss","content":"h","created_at":"2014-07-07T10:07:02.398Z","updated_at":"2014-07-07T10:07:02.398Z"}]{"id":12,"name":"lo","title":"gi","content":"c","created_at":"2014-07-08T05:26:05.816Z","updated_at":"2014-07-08T05:26:05.816Z"}
```

when i use **obj.name** it is nt displaying any data how can i display all my data.

Comment: I don't know which output you get at which point, but `data` is clearly an array, so you have to access one of its elements and get its name. The array itself doesn't have a name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: The output i mentioned for data :  i got that output when i use console.log(data).  After parsing it i got second output

Comment: Yeah, but the first output shows that `data` is already an array of objects (so no need to parse it). And second output implies that `obj` is a string which I find very hard to believe if the result comes from `JSON.parse`. It should throw an error if `data` is already an array.

Comment: It doesn't throw any error. And after parsing i got output in "[ ]" square braces. I think we should not have []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is use the Chrome developer tools to set a breakpoint in your code at the point in which you get a response and set it to a variable. At this point Chrome has a console you can use to view objects and execute javascript. It is incredibly handy for situations like this.

It looks like the data is coming back as a list, so you would want to do something like this.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var name = data[i].name;
    // you can manipulate the DOM here with the name
}
```

Comment: i got response for data in object format which i mentioned in my question after parsing i got another format now i have to display that data

Comment: Yea, if you just play around with the console you could see what happens when you do obj.name. Im not a javascript expert, but you might have to do obj['name']. Ive had that issue in the past

Comment: It is not displaying any thing if you observe the second output that is after parsing I am getting output in "[ ]" square braces. but i think we should not have that braces

Comment: You should probably check the value of the variable `data` before you parse it to ensure that a value exists. If it does, I would use breakpoints and manually check all the response before and after it gets parsed to see where it is going wrong

Comment: But does it have the expected contents?

Comment: The output after parsing is of the format [{"id":1,"name":"sdh"},{"id":1,"name":"sdh"},{"id":1,"name":"sdh"}]. now i need to display name from this output how can i the data is enclosed in between square braces

Comment: So your response is coming back as a list. You're gonna have to iterate over it to grab what you need

Comment: I have solved it before in the same manner but thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The leading `[` in your data indicates an array:

```
[{"id":10,"name":"ss","title":"ss","content":"h","created_at":"2014-07-07T10:07:02.398Z","updated_at":"2014-07-07T10:07:02.398Z"},{"id":12,"name":"lo","title":"gi","content":"c","created_at":"2014-07-08T05:26:05.816Z","updated_at":"2014-07-08T05:26:05.816Z"}]
```

In other words, `obj` is an array containing multiple objects. Each of those objects has parameters `id`, `name`, `title`, and so on.

So, you want to access `obj[0].name`, `obj[1].name`, etc., not just `obj.name`.

Note: There was a typo in the post-parsing data that you provided in the question. It looks like it should be what I have above. If you still have problems, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information. I have changed my succes function as success: function(data) {  
 var obj = JSON.parse(data);
 alert(obj[0].name);      But it is not showing alert box

Comment: I process worked for data output not for obj that is data[0].name got worked

Comment: one small think i want to say is json means javascript object notation the output i got in data is of object format so i think there is no need of parsing it. Am i thinking it in correct format

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question; if you got the output shown for the object, then yes, you are getting back a JSON object with no need to parse it. If you are able to parse it and getting the data specified, then that indicates that you actually got a string. How did you produce the values in your question?

Comment: just by using data[0].name i got output.    My data contains object then after parsing it i got output of the format [{"id":1,"name":"jhdb"},{"id":1,"name":"jhdb"},{"id":1,"name":"jhdb"}] then what is the above format is called after parsing

Comment: Try logging `data` to the console in Chrome (`console.log(data)`), then try logging the parsed version (`console.log(JSON.parse(data))`). Something is very wrong with your AJAX response if you are able to parse `data` but my solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: what is the difference between two outputs i specified both are called as array of objects but the format is different why? any answer

Comment: I can't really answer this because I can't tell what output you're actually getting. The presence of the word `Object` in the first version makes it look like your browser is trying to convert an object, but then you post the converted version, which looks like a JSON object. One of these is incorrect, but I have no way of knowing which one. Either use `data` without calling `JSON.parse`, or call `JSON.parse` and use the result -- I can't tell which you need based on the information given. Either way, you need to use the data as an array, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the convenience method

`$.getJSON('/someurl',function(jsonReturnedFromServer){
 });`

You may have to debug it to ensure you're getting valid json back from the server

Comment: I have seen this method but my task is to use only .ajax method